# Accesing multiple sub folders with QDir

Tags: qt, qt5, qdir

Could not find my solution in prior posts. How can I read all the files from out of my resource folder which has multiple subfolders.
For example the file structure:

```
fonts/test1
  ...test1.ttf
fonts/test2
  ...test2.otf
fonts/test3
  ...test3.woff2
  ...test3.woff
```

This is what I currently have, I'm just not entirely sure how to modify to what I want.

```
QStringList fontFileList = QDir(":/fonts/fonts/").entryList(QStringList() , QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotDot | QDir::NoDot);
qDebug() << fontFileList;
```

---

.qrc content

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/fonts">
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-Black.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-BlackItalic.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-Bold.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-BoldItalic.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-ExtraBold.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-ExtraLight.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-ExtraLightItalic.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-Italic.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-Light.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-LightItalic.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-Regular.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-SemiBold.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/Muli/Muli-SemiBoldItalic.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/FontAwesome/Font_Awesome_5_Pro-Regular-400.otf</file>
        <file>fonts/FontAwesome/Font_Awesome_5_pro-solid-900.otf</file>
        <file>fonts/bebas_neue/BebasNeue-Regular.woff</file>
        <file>fonts/bebas_neue/BebasNeue-Regular.woff2</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Post updated  with the .qrc content

Comment: The `qDebug() << fontFileList` outputs `()`

Comment: Use QDirIterator: `QDirIterator it(":/fonts/fonts/",  QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotDot | QDir::NoDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);`
   `while (it.hasNext())`
        `fontFileList << it.next();`